# Split string with shifting pattern in perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

I have:

```
my $string = aaaa bbbb "ccccc ddddd eeee" fffff "ggggg hhhh";
```

I want split this string to:

```
aaaa    
bbbb
cccc dddd eeee
ffff
gggg hhhh
```

How I can do it using split?

I think that it should look something like this pseudo-code:

```
split(/IF ONWARD SYMBOL " APPEARS EVENT COUNT DO PATTERN: \s ELSE: "/ $string);
```

Note: need to preserve the order of characters in a string

Comment: Where is your code failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `split` it is best to use a global regex to divide the string into quoted and non-quoted parts.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'aaaa bbbb "ccccc ddddd eeee" fffff "ggggg hhhh"';

my @split = $string =~ / " [^"]* " | \S+ /xg;

print "$_\n" for @split;
```

**output**

```
aaaa
bbbb
"ccccc ddddd eeee"
fffff
"ggggg hhhh"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the handy module [`Text::ParseWords`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aParseWords) from the Perl core library:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $string = qq(aaaa bbbb "ccccc ddddd eeee" fffff "ggggg hhhh");
my @parts = quotewords('\s+', 0, $string);
print Dumper \@parts;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'aaaa',
          'bbbb',
          'ccccc ddddd eeee',
          'fffff',
          'ggggg hhhh'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match words inside and ouside double quotes separately, and use `/g` in a loop, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'aaaa bbbb "ccccc ddddd eeee" fffff "ggggg hhhh"';

while ($string =~ m/(\w+)|"([^"]+)"/g) {
    print $1 || $2, "\n";
}
```

---

Running:

```
$ perl t.pl 
aaaa
bbbb
ccccc ddddd eeee
fffff
ggggg hhhh
```

---

By the way, you can achieve the above in just one line:

```
@field = grep { defined } ( $string =~ m/(\w+)|"([^"]+)"/g );
```

Comment: I am sure that the example string isn't live data, and it is quite likely that the real data fields don't match `\w+`

Comment: It's useful to note that you can use the *branch reset* pattern `(?| ... )` here, which has the effect of storing all captures within a list of alternatives into the same variable. So `m/ (?| (\w+) | "([^"]+)" ) /xg` would set `$1` regardless of which branch actually matched. You could also write just `print $1 || $2` within the `while` loop

Comment: @Borodin Thank you very much for your suggestions. Answer updated, the first version is much better now. `(?| ... )` introduced in Perl 5.10.0, but unfortunately I am use Perl 5.8.8 at this moment. However, it is still good to know it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A way with split:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = '"aaaa" bbbb kkkk "ccccc ddddd eeee" fffff eeee "ggggg hhhh"';

my @res = grep {$_} split(/ *"([^"]*)" *| +/, $string);

print join($/, @res);
```